# Detect number of cv.Circles on a frame in python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have taken some python code snippet from somewhere, in which the circles are drawn as the following:

```
cv.Circle(color_image, point, 2, cv.CV_RGB(255, 255, 0), 6)
```

Sometimes there is only one circle on the screen, but sometimes more than 1 circle on the screen.

How can I detect the number of circles on the screen in python opencv? Is there such a ready method for that?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show an example?  The circle drawing method in OpenCV is only designed to draw one circle at a time. I don't understand how it can draw "more than one circle" on the screen.

Comment: Yes it is. But let's say if there are more than 1 circle were drawn on the image before, and if the circle is existed, how can I detect that how many circles were drawn?

Comment: Yup... `cv.FindContours`: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours.  However, if you have overlapping circles, the find contours algorithm will consider this as one object so this is not fool proof.  Simply check how many contours are returned from the algorithm and that gives you an indication of how many circles are drawn... however, the glaring assumption is that the image should **only** consist of these circles and nothing else.  If you have some complex background or something happening in the background, this won't work.

Comment: it depends on what you mean by a circle because if you draw one circle you have already 3 circles